# Get view's name in serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a serilizer. I have overridden the `to_representation` method of the serializer. I want to use the view name for which the serializer code has been invoked. I tried the following::

```
self.context['view'].__class__
```

This returns me the following::

```
<class 'search.api.v1.views.JobSearchList'>
```

However, I just want the name of the view class. i.e. `JobSearchList`

Any idea how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can get the name by

```
self.context['view'].__class__.__name__
# or type(self.context['view']).__name__  something like that.
```

Comment: Yeah my bad.. Got the answer. Anyways thanks for the effort.